# Firebase users and information

Tags: firebase, app-inventor

How do I store profile information for users in App Inventor using Firebase (e.g:Full name, age, some answers to some question that need to be displayed on his profile)?

I tried the Auth extension, but it doesn't provide too many options. Do I make use of user's UID?

Comment: Why not store all the information in database and fetch it (e.g. add observer) when use’s authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Using their user ID, save their data in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) or [Realtime Database.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) Then you can retrieve and store any data you want.